# Passing MDX parameters to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, mdx

I have several reports that are from SSAS 2008, but one of them has to drill through to a SQL Server report simply because the data is far to granular for a cube.

Any tips on passing parameters? Of course they are passed in as MDX, and I can't figure out a way to get just the "Key" with the source MDX. Surprisingly I can't find a lot of pointers on this.

Let me know if this is too vague...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting the MDX passed in as a string which you can examine and fiddle with? If you can extract the dimension and member name, you could look up the name in the SQL database to find the ID required, which could then be passed on?

I assume you are getting strings like this:
`[Location].[All location].[South].[Surrey].[Guildford]`
If you look up 'Guildford' in your SQL db you'll be able to find out it is row 2134 and that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to call this report from a report action. If your attribute has a single column key you can reference it using something like:

```
[<dimension>].[<hierarchy>].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY")
```

If your attribute has multiple key columns you would use KEY0, KEY1, etc to reference the individual parts instead of MEMBER_KEY